# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: MyBean#MyBean not found

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb

I have a multi module maven project which contains a jar module (models), two EJB modules (repository, service) and a web module.
The first thing that may cause the problem is that I don't know in which EJB module should I place the persistence.xml file.

It looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">

   <persistence-unit name="jthrdb">

        <jta-data-source>MySQL</jta-data-source>

   </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

I've also tried placing it in both repository and service modules (src/main/resources/META-INF) but I'm still getting this exception:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: MyBean#MyBean not found
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.doLookup(TransientContext.java:237)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:204)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:66)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:478)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.resolveEjbReference(EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.java:183)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.ComponentEnvManagerImpl$EjbReferenceProxy.create(ComponentEnvManagerImpl.java:1143)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:745)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:715)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:159)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:471)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:613)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:484)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectInstance(InjectionManagerImpl.java:141)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectInstance(InjectionManagerImpl.java:127)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.createManagedObject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:324)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.createServletInstance(WebContainer.java:983)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.createServletInstance(WebModule.java:2130)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1404)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:1211)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:237)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

Here's a part of the servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/MyServlet")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EJB
private CandidateBean bean;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public MyServlet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
 *      response)
 */
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    Candidate temp = new Candidate();
    temp.setFirstName("Pos");
    // bean.insert(temp);
    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<body>");
    out.println("<h1>" + bean.saySomething() + "</h1>");
    out.println("</body>");
    out.println("</html>");
}
}
```

Comment: Please provide servlet code and web.xml where are you using MyBean.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any EJBs in persistence.xml, this file is JPA configuration file where you configure your persistence layer. Here are the steps you should do (I did not delve deeply into Glassfish configuration, because you have to create a MySQL JDBC data source called jdbc/MySQL, and persistence unit reference into into EJBs, for that please consult Glassfish documentation).

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
        <persistence-unit name="jthrdb" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/MySQL</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.test.MyJpaEntity</class>
        </persistence-unit>
   </persistence>

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "jthrdb")
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

and then in EJB methods use

```
entityManager.persist(myJpaEntity);
```

Another thing I've spotted: in persistence.xml you are using JPA 1.0. Most modern application servers and Spring support JPA 2.0 or event better 2.1 usage that has improved API and is definitively a better choice (I have added persistence 2.0 configuration here).

Comment: I changed the JPA to 2.0. The problem still exists. In the servlet I have a simple `entityManager.insert()` method that invokes this exception. Another problem is that it can't create automatically the tables in the mysql schema. I can't find the problem.

Comment: The error you mentioned here is not related to JPA - the problem here is with EJB MyBean that cannot be found in JNDI context. Do you have in servlet something like @EJB private MyBean;

Comment: I have reached the point where the JPA can create the entity tables in the database. You were right, it's not JPA related, but then what? I'm getting the same exception.

Comment: Please post part of code in your servlet where are you referencing MyBean. Also, please post ejb-jar.xml configuration file of EJB project where MyBean is defined (only part where MyBean is defined would be enough).

Comment: Okay, here's the servlet. I've found out that the ejb-jar.xml file is missing, so I tried to write it, but I don't know what to write in the `<ejb-name></ejb-name>` part in order to work properly.

Comment: In your case ejb-jar.xml is not required, as you are using annotations. What is weird here is that in stack trace MyBean is not found, and in servlet you have CandidateBean. Do you have WAR and EJB-JAR modules packaged into EAR? Is CandidateBean no-interface, Local or Remote Bean?

Comment: I named here the CandidateBean as MyBean and forgot to rename it in the update. Yes, they're both packaged in the EAR. The CandidateBean is a Stateless Bean which implements a Local interface.

Comment: The problem was solved by adding a @LocalBean annotation to the CandidateBean. Now it's working fine. :D

Comment: I thought it was something like that :-) I'm glad it's fixed now.